# How do I extract meaningful simple rules from this classification problem?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, rules, interaction

I have a problem of this type: A customer creates an order by hand, which might be erroneous. Submitting a wrong order is costly, which is why we try to reduce the error rate.

I need to detect what factors cause an error, so that a new rule can be created, such as Product "A" and type "B" must not go together. All explanatory variables are categorical.

I have 2 questions:

1. What approach do I take to extract simple but useful rules to give to a human expert for further review? A useful rule should cover as many errors as possible while covering as few non-errors as possible.
2. How do I make sure variable interactions are taken into account?

Below is a sample dataset and a simple approach I took -- finding variables with high proportion of errors to be proposed as rules. I create a single interaction term by hand (based on prior knowledge, but I might be missing others).

I also tried using classification models (LASSO, Decision tree, RF), but I had an issue with 1. high dimensionality (especially when including many interactions), 2. extracting simple rules, since models use many coefficients even with regularization.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create sample dataset for task
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'error':[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],
                        'product':[1,2,1,2,2,3,4,2,2,2],
                        'type':[1,1,2,3,3,1,2,1,4,4],
                        'discount_level':[5,3,3,4,1,2,2,1,4,5],
                        'extra1':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,],
                        'extra2':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1],
                        'extra3':[6,6,9,9,8,8,7,7,6,6]
                        })

# Variable interaction based on prior knowledge
df['product_type'] = df['product'].astype(str) + '_' + df['type'].astype(str)
X = df.drop('error', axis=1)

# Find groups with high portion of errors
groups_expl = pd.DataFrame()
for col in X.columns:
    groups = df.groupby(col).agg(count_all=('error', 'count'),
                                 count_error=('error', 'sum'))
    groups['portion_error'] = groups['count_error'] / groups['count_all']
    groups['column'] = col

    # Save groups with high portion of errors
    groups_expl = pd.concat([groups_expl, groups.loc[groups['portion_error']>0.8, :]], axis=0)
    groups_expl['col_val'] = groups_expl.index

print(groups_expl)
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What approach do I take to extract simple but useful rules to give to a human expert for further review?

You could experiment with a shallow bagging model. For example, `XGBClassifier(n_estimators = 100, max_depth = 2)`.

The idea is that each ensemble element comes to represent some feature combination that corresponds to elevated risk.

> How do I make sure variable interactions are taken into account?

Decision tree models are easy to visualize and interpret, and they do feature interactions automatically.

Imagine the following split logic:

```
if product == 1:
  if extra == 3:
    return "high risk"
  else:
    return "no risk"
else
  return "no risk"
```

As you can see, this decision tree only contributes towards the total risk score when `product == 1 and extra == 3`. That's a feature interaction.

Comment: One question -- if the trees split on for example variables A, B, then C. Is there a way to tell if there is an interaction between A and B, or these are two separate signals, just that A is stronger than B?

Comment: You can simplify or complicate the generated rules by decreasing or increasing tree depth, respectively. In my example, I limited `max_depth` to 2, because in this case each tree uses two (different-) features max. Your situation requires `max_depth` of 3, or above. You could train tree ensembles with different tree depths - 2, 3 and 4, and see if adding complexity to rules improves the statistical performance or not. If `max_depth` values of 2 and 4 yield close statistical performance, then go with 2, as those rules will be much easier to interpret.

Comment: About your specific question - given a sequence of three splits A -> B -> C, then I'd assume that we have two consequtive feature interactions there: 1) A <-> B and 2) B <-> C. Of course, there is 3) A <-> C (because it's the same logic chain), but it's definitely a weaker/less obvious interaction than the former two. You can "measure" interaction strength by observing the associated tree lead values - they are the risk estimates, afterall.

Comment: BTW: there are many libraries (in the Scikit-Learn/Python world) available for converting shallow decision tree ensembles into "condensed" rule sets. You may want to try out these. But it's important that you understand the base logic first, as given in this current SO thread.

Comment: Thank you, please if you have anything specific in mind as for conversion to "condensed" rule sets, let me know -- this will be my next step. 
I'm not sure I understand the interactions: if let's say in truth, A-->Y (strongly) and B-->Y (weakly), but A and B are uncorrelated. My guess would be shallow bagging would include A first and B second, even though there is no interaction (as I understand it).

Comment: In case of deeper trees, the leading tree levels simply partition the original dataset into smaller subsets. Take note, interactions and correlations are very likely subset-dependent. For example, a sequence of tree splits A -> B -> C could also have a meaning: "split the original dataset into two subsets by A; in the left subset, there is a feature interaction between B and C that represents such-and-such elevated risk scenario".

Comment: Search for "extract rules from fitted decision trees"

Comment: And yes, in case of bagging models, earlier trees have more significance than later trees. For example, the first tree is the most important, because it starts from an empty sheet, and therefore can change the risk estimate "from first principles". In contrast, tree number 100 is trying to adjust a risk estimate that is already very-very close to the optimal solution.